# How can I get the WSDL of soap service using Qorus UI?

Tags: soap, wsdl, qore

I'm trying to get the WSDL of a soap service, I know that somehow it's possible to get the WSDL from Qorus UI, but seems that I'm not able to get the right URL. can some one please indicate the right way? Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<BASE URL>/SOAP/<NAME OF SERVCE or API>

so for example:

https://localhost:11930/SOAP/my-soap-test

will print you WSDL of the service

Answer (score 2):

also if you are running Qorus 3.1.0.p15+ with the react web UI, you can go to Services -> Detail -> Resources -> Show Info and you will get a link to the WSDL as the the following screenshot:

[image: Qorus service WSDL resource link]

Or you can get this information from the command line with a request like the following:

```
david@quasar:~/src/qore/git/qore/build$ qrest services/it-86-ar_receipts-wincash-in/resources
hash: (1 member)
  soap-it-86-ar_receipts-wincash-in-1 : hash: (3 members)
    type : "SoapServer"
    desc : "serving path: /SOAP/ARReceiptsService"
    info : hash: (3 members)
      path : "/SOAP/ARReceiptsService"
      url : "https://localhost:8011/SOAP/ARReceiptsService"
      wsdl : "https://localhost:8011/SOAP/ARReceiptsService?wsdl"
```

Comment: Thank you for the brief answer.